# nodejs return array of objects from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I want to return an array of objects that contains collection name and its documents count for each object, e.g. 
[ { col:col1, count:1 } , { col:col2, count:2} ]

Currently I only return an array of document count for each collection, by resolving the query as a promise.

My main issue is returning an object from the .map function because it must return promises instead.

```
db.listCollections()
  .toArray()
  .then(collections => {
    let promises = collections.map(col => {

      // Cannot return {col,count} here :/
      return db.collection(col["name"]).countDocuments();
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, passing an `async` function to `collections.map()`, you *could* return `{ col, count }`:

```
db.listCollections()
  .toArray()
  .then(collections => {
    const promises = collections.map(async col => {
      return {
        col: col.name,
        count: await db.collection(col.name).countDocuments()
      };
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(res => { console.log(res); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with

```
return Promise.all([
    db.collection(col["name"]).countDocuments(),
    Promise.resolve(col["name"])
]);
```

Comment: The `Promise.resolve()` around `col["name"]` is not necessary, and you also don't need a computed property to do that, so the simplified answer would be `return Promise.all([db.collection(col.name).countDocuments(), col.name])`